# Question about pointwise convergence and discontinuities

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Suppose $f_n \rightarrow f$ on $A$. If every $f_n$ has finitely many discontinuities, does $f$ have finitely many discontinuities?

I know that pointwise continuity doesn't necessarily preserve discontinuity, (or lack thereof) but I'm having trouble thinking of a sequence of functions with finitely many discontinuities and make it converge to a function with either $0$ discontinuities or infinitely many discontinuities.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to find an example where $f_n$ has $n$ discontinuities.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f_n: (0,1)\to \Bbb{R}$ such that $f_n(x) = 1$ for $x= \frac{1}{n}$, and $f_n(x)=0$ otherwise. Then $(f_n)$ converges pointwise to the zero function. Each $f_n$ has one discontinuity, and they pointwise converge to a continuous function.

As another example, define $f_n$ as follows (with the same domain as before): $f_n(x) = 1$ if $x=\frac{1}{m}$ for $1\leq m \leq n$ (where $m\in \Bbb{N}$), and $f_n(x) = 0$ otherwise. Then each $f_n$ has finitely many discontinuities ($n-1$, to be exact), but the limit has infinitely many.